# Совпадение слов в двух DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть два DataFrame:
a - исходные строки, в которых нужно искать совпадение

b - cписок, из которого нужно взять значение из колонки Brand_custom и в случае совпадения слова подставить значение из колонки Brand

```
a = {'file_brand': ['Производитель PERFECT COLOURANTS AND PLASTICS PVT. LTD. тов. знак A-LEN TECH артикул AD 1290 кол-во=384', 
                               'Производитель SABIC PETROCHEMICALS B.V. тов. знак SABIC марка ОТСУТСТВУЕТ', 
                               'Производитель TIANJIN ENERGY MASTER TECHNOLOGY CO., LTD тов. знак ОТСУТСТВУЕТ артикул YM20230801 кол-во=19.36', 
                               'Производитель "SK CORP.", КОРЕЯ РЕСП. тов. знак "SK"', 
                               'Производитель KH MOTORSPARTS CO.LTD тов. знак MOBIS марка MOBIS артикул SP-IV RR модель ATF кол-во=360', 
                               'Производитель AKITA KAIHATSU G.K. тов. знак NGN марка NGN артикул V182575116 модель NGN A-LINE 5W-30 кол-во=80', 
                               'Производитель ANGLO INTERNATIONAL MINING B.V. тов. знак AIMOL марка AIMOL артикул 8717662391033 модель AIMOL X-COOL CONCENTRATE 3122 кол-во=20', 
                               'Производитель WD-40 COMPANY LTD тов. знак WD-40 марка WD-40 артикул ОТСУТСТВУЕТ модель WD-40 кол-во=3792', 
                               'Производитель TURCAS PETROL A.S. тов. знак SMARTOIL марка ОТСУТСТВУЕТ артикул 11028256 модель SMARTOIL 3000 кол-во=48', 
                               'Производитель COLUMBIA PETRO CHEM PVT LTD тов. знак ОТСУТСТВУЕТ марка 15 USP артикул ОТСУТСТВУЕТ модель 15 USP кол-во=11.90']}
 
b = {'Brand_custom': ['A-LEN TECH', 'SABIC', 'SK', 'MOBIS', 'NGN', 'AIMOL', 'SMARTOIL'],
     'Brand': ['A-LEN TECH', 'SABIC', 'SK', 'MOBIS', 'NGN', 'AIMOL', 'SMARTOIL']}
```

Но код выдает значение только для первой строки, а остальные "-"

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
brand_df = pd.DataFrame(data=b)

df['Corr_Brand'] = ''

def check_Brand(row):
    for i in range(brand_df.shape[0]):
        if brand_df.loc[i]['Brand_custom'] in row['file_brand']:
            return brand_df.loc[i]['Brand']
        else:
            return '-'

df['Corr_Brand'] = df.apply(check_Brand, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, просто сделать маппер и замену?

```
mapper = dict(zip(*b.values()))
df['Corr_Brand'] = df['file_brand'].apply(lambda x:
                                          next(iter([val for key, val in mapper.items()
                                                     if key in x]),"-"))
print(df)
```

```
                                          file_brand  Corr_Brand
0  Производитель PERFECT COLOURANTS AND PLASTICS ...  A-LEN TECH
1  Производитель SABIC PETROCHEMICALS B.V. тов. з...       SABIC
2  Производитель TIANJIN ENERGY MASTER TECHNOLOGY...           -
3  Производитель "SK CORP.", КОРЕЯ РЕСП. тов. зна...          SK
4  Производитель KH MOTORSPARTS CO.LTD тов. знак ...       MOBIS
5  Производитель AKITA KAIHATSU G.K. тов. знак NG...         NGN
6  Производитель ANGLO INTERNATIONAL MINING B.V. ...       AIMOL
7  Производитель WD-40 COMPANY LTD тов. знак WD-4...           -
8  Производитель TURCAS PETROL A.S. тов. знак SMA...    SMARTOIL
9  Производитель COLUMBIA PETRO CHEM PVT LTD тов....           -
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну видимо возврат отрицательного результата нужно делать после окончания цикла, а не после первой же не удавшейся проверки:

```py
def check_Brand(row):
    for i in range(brand_df.shape[0]):
        if brand_df.iloc[i]['Brand_custom'] in row['file_brand']:
            return brand_df.iloc[i]['Brand']
    # все бренды проверили, совпадений нет
    return '-'
```

Comment: я не понимаю... когда запускаю код на тесте все работает. А если вместо "a" и "b" считываю excel файлы, в которых как раз колонки, не получается ```Corr_Data_File = "D:\My_Work_Phoenix\Таможня\Product names.xlsx"
Customs_Folder = "D:\My_Work_Phoenix\Таможня\Customs_test.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(Customs_Folder)
brand_df = pd.read_excel(Corr_Data_File, sheet_name='Brands')```  Ошибка: File "D:\My_Python_Projects\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3809, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 2

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Masik84/c75bf5b77d1e35e53d8d2111b09c83fa

Comment: А попробуйте использовать `iloc` вместо `loc`, я исправил код.

Answer (score 0):

Регуляркой извлекаем вхождения меток брендов. Где они есть - появляется ключ-метка, где нет - NaN. Далее просто заменяем ключи-метки по словарю на названия брендов, который делаем путем преобразования из `b`. NaN'ы заменяем на `-`.

```
df['Corr_Brand'] = df['file_brand'].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(b['Brand_custom']) + ')').replace({k: v for k, v in zip(b['Brand_custom'], b['Brand'])}).fillna('-')
```

```
                                                                                                                                       file_brand  Corr_Brand
0                                         Производитель PERFECT COLOURANTS AND PLASTICS PVT. LTD. тов. знак A-LEN TECH артикул AD 1290 кол-во=384  A-LEN TECH
1                                                                       Производитель SABIC PETROCHEMICALS B.V. тов. знак SABIC марка ОТСУТСТВУЕТ       SABIC
2                                   Производитель TIANJIN ENERGY MASTER TECHNOLOGY CO., LTD тов. знак ОТСУТСТВУЕТ артикул YM20230801 кол-во=19.36           -
3                                                                                            Производитель "SK CORP.", КОРЕЯ РЕСП. тов. знак "SK"          SK
4                                          Производитель KH MOTORSPARTS CO.LTD тов. знак MOBIS марка MOBIS артикул SP-IV RR модель ATF кол-во=360       MOBIS
5                                  Производитель AKITA KAIHATSU G.K. тов. знак NGN марка NGN артикул V182575116 модель NGN A-LINE 5W-30 кол-во=80         NGN
6  Производитель ANGLO INTERNATIONAL MINING B.V. тов. знак AIMOL марка AIMOL артикул 8717662391033 модель AIMOL X-COOL CONCENTRATE 3122 кол-во=20       AIMOL
7                                        Производитель WD-40 COMPANY LTD тов. знак WD-40 марка WD-40 артикул ОТСУТСТВУЕТ модель WD-40 кол-во=3792           -
8                           Производитель TURCAS PETROL A.S. тов. знак SMARTOIL марка ОТСУТСТВУЕТ артикул 11028256 модель SMARTOIL 3000 кол-во=48    SMARTOIL
9                     Производитель COLUMBIA PETRO CHEM PVT LTD тов. знак ОТСУТСТВУЕТ марка 15 USP артикул ОТСУТСТВУЕТ модель 15 USP кол-во=11.90           -
```

Если словарь замен сразу сделать вида `метка:бренд`, то его можно применять без преобразования.
**Ниже - более оптимальный код** - если сделать словарь сразу более удобным:

```
b = {'A-LEN TECH': 'A-LEN TECH', 'SABIC': 'SABIC', 'SK': 'SK', 'MOBIS': 'MOBIS', 'NGN': 'NGN', 'AIMOL': 'AIMOL', 'SMARTOIL': 'SMARTOIL'}
df['Corr_Brand'] = df['file_brand'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(b.keys())})').replace(b).fillna('-')
```